# Trying to get Azure AD onPremisesSamAccountName from Microsoft using oAuth and REST

Tags: azure, coldfusion, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I attempt to retrieve the sAMAccountName from Azure AD via Microsoft Graph and oAuth, the attribute is not returned.

I am trying to retrieve the onPremisesSamAccountName through oAuth from Microsoft Graph on my Azure AD tenant. My local domain syncs with Azure, and I have selected the sAMAccountName directory extension for syncing. However, when I make my GET request to the Graph REST URI, I get back the correct user object, but I don't get back the onPremisesSamAccountName.

Here is my request:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/user@domain.com?api_version=1.6
```

That request returns the user object with a truckload of properties. When I try the following (in the hopes of "$select"ing the field, Microsoft returns the metadata URL--which actually contains the onPremisesSamAccountName property definition.

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/user@somain.com?api-version=1.6&$select=onPremisesSamAccountName
```

Am I not formatting my query correctly? In the Azure AD portal, I have the following API permissions specified:

[image: Image of API permissions]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Graph API to get `onPremisesSamAccountName` property. [Here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) is the Microsoft Graph explorer.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userObjectId}?$select=onPremisesSamAccountName
```

[image]

By the way, the permissions you granted are Microsoft graph api permissions, not Azure AD graph api permissions. [Azure AD graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) is different from [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview). It is recommended to use Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: I got what I needed out of that. Thank you.